# Redirecting traffic from multiple folders to single folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have several old event pages on my site that date back years and I want to delete them and then have all traffic that might hit them to be redirected to the root of a new events section.

So:

```
http://my_site.com/event2009/
http://my_site.com/event2009/info.php
http://my_site.com/event2009/sub_directory/
http://my_site.com/event2010/
http://my_site.com/event2011/
...
```

Gets redirected to:

```
http://my_site.com/events/
```

Basically I want all traffic that is going to 6 folders to go to the root of a new folder.

Sorry if this had been asked before but it's difficult to sum up on the a title and there for hard to also search for.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} -gt $1
RewriteRule ^event(\d+) /events/ [R,L]
```

If it does not work, replace the `RewriteCond` with:

```
RewriteCond $1 -le 2015
```

An issue with the latter would be that you'd need to update `2015` every year.

Comment: Both those solutions caused and 500 error. I think that I am looking for is little simpler. As there are only 5 folders that and there child files that need redirecting. (event2006, event2007, event2008, event2010 and event2011). Regular expression confuse the crap out of me but is the code above meant to catch folders that have year less then 2015?

Comment: Can you check apache error logs to see what causes the server error?